# Remove columns based on a its cumsum

Tags: r

Starting Dataset:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   1   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   1   0   0   1
0   0   0   0   1   0   0
```

Desired Output:

```
B   D   E   G
0   0   0   0
1   1   0   1
0   0   0   0
0   1   0   1
0   0   0   0
1   1   0   1
0   0   1   0
```

So my thought was to use try to group columns by their cumsum and if that sum was == 0 then I could remove them, But for some reason I haven't been able to get this to work. I have thousands of columns like this to delete. I understand how to do it one at a time, I can't seem to get things to scale to all the columns that I need to delete. My excel brain is still holding me back. I have been gravitating toward dplyr so far in the script I am writing, but I haven't been able to crack this one yet.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only 1/0's in the data, you can use :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select(where(~sum(.) != 0))
#select_if in older version of dplyr
#df %>% select_if(~sum(.) != 0)

#  B D E G
#1 0 0 0 0
#2 1 1 0 1
#3 0 0 0 0
#4 0 1 0 1
#5 0 0 0 0
#6 1 1 0 1
#7 0 0 1 0
```

If you also have negative numbers in your data, you can check if `any` value is not equal to 0 and select that column.

```
df %>% select(where(~any(. != 0)))
#df %>% select_if(~any(. != 0))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B = c(0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), C = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), E = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), F = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), G = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Cheers, I have two clarifications that I wanted to ask about. First, when I run that code on my dataset, which does contain all numeric values (no chars or any other factors) I get the error:  `workingFile <- workingFile %>% select(where(~sum(.) != 0))
Error: where() must be used with functions that return TRUE or FALSE`.`

Comment: @PlotDevice Can you test it using the data in my post? Does the code work for it? Also `where` is introduced in `dplyr` 1.0.0 so you need to have the latest `dplyr` or use `select_if`, `df %>% select_if(~sum(.) != 0)`

Comment: The second is if I have non-numeric columns, how to I ignore those, select the range, then delete the selected columns in the range without deleting the columns I ignored?

Comment: Ah nm, re the error. I thought I have the latest version of dplyr, but the select_if worked like a charm.  The second clarification I am poking at, but haven't figured it out yet

Comment: If you want to select columns in range with numeric column without deleting non- numeric column, you can try `df %>% select_if(~is.numeric(.) && sum(.) != 0 || !is.numeric(.))`

Comment: I need to go down the rabbit hole of all these helper funtions. They keep tripping me up. That looks like it worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For dataframe `mydf`, assuming values are all 0 or 1:

```
new_df <- mydf[colSums(mydf) > 0]
```